# Which statistical tests should be used for significance difference

Tags: machine-learning, p-value, hypothesis-testing

Some of my recent papers are denied from publications, where I have used the non-parametric wilcoxon test and the reviewers raised objections that p-values are not the reliable way of identifying the significance differences.

If we have to compare and contrast the performance of two or more algorithms on the same data (lets say we have continous non-normalized data), which are the most reliable and unbiased statistical tests to be performed on the results we obtained? I have read some papers that are published in good venues and they have used p-values but my papers get rejected often, where mostly the reason is p-values.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume that your question decudes to "why p-value is unreliable measure". As a person with Statistics background, I would agree with the decision in a manner that p-values are really not reliable way to reasoning a hypothesis test. There is a great deal of discussions about this problem lately after and around 90s.

It's considered as an unreliable measure since the fixed cut-offs do not actually represents the amount of confidence, and it does not embrace the idea of "being different" it's truly a subjective cut-off point decided by the experimenter. Thus, I personally believe that p-values are not truly redundant, but I strongly agree that the experimenter would not use a fixed cut-off point to justify the decisions. Rather I personally use p-value solely as a probability measure without cut-off to gain some insight, but not to justify.

I think this is the main reason behind unreliability of p-value. However, we have yet to see another measure for hypothesis tests or even a different way of conducting and testing experiments so far.

**Further reading**

1. [Why P Values Are Not a Useful Measure of Evidence in Statistical
   Significance Testing](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240281208_Why_P_Values_Are_Not_a_Useful_Measure_of_Evidence_in_Statistical_Significance_Testing)
2. [Why the P-value culture is bad and
   confidence intervals a better alternative](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1063458412007789)
3. [Most of the time, P
   is an unreliable marker, so we need no exact cut-off](https://academic.oup.com/bja/article/116/6/894/2566641)

Comment: thank you for the detailed information. Ok p-values are not reliable, so we can not use t-tes, wilcoxon test etc. But what are the alternatives? Which tests should be used instead, so we can get evidence that one algorithm is significantly better than the other algorithm. Some people have used the effect size tests, but in the majority of the articles I have read, they used the effect size tests along with the p-values (e.g. wilcoxon test).

Comment: Well, I did not say that you cannot use stastical tests, I just argued that it is not proper to "justify" with fixed cut-off on p-value. By the way, I am assuming that you compare computational performance of several algos and not comparing machine learning models performance right ? So if you compare computational performance of different algorithms you can maybe compare by mean/median values (a common choice) of k runs simply. If you edit your question and add some papers you read using statistical tests and p-values, I will check. However, if you compare ML models, you're completely lost.

Comment: I meaning the comparison of ML models, so how I lost? To compare the performance of  two ML models like svm and nn, don't we need to use the statistical tests or some effect size tests?

Comment: I'd like to look at the papers you mentioned which uses statistical tests for model performances. To compare ml models you compare the predictive performance, and the trivial and common thing here is to use test errors of best run of k runs, or in terms of loss you take the median of k runs, etc. that's how it usually works, reporting predictive perfomance metrics of best run of k runs. I have not seen any well known paper to compare via statistical test, they just straightforwardly report the test error for example of best model of k runs.

Comment: this is one of the paper which used wilcoxon test and effect size test for the performance comparison. There are others too, that are published in good venues.. http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/F.Sarro/resource/papers/SarroICSE2016.pdf